# How to use different types of store for each page with next-redux-wrapper

Tags: redux, next.js, next-redux-wrapper

`next-redux-wrapper` forces me to structure different pages using a single type of store. But different pages mostly have a lot different states, which can lead debugging a page through devtools messed up with too many unused properties.

How to use different types of store for each page with `next-redux-wrapper`? Or solutions not using this module can be suggested if I can solve `Cannot update a component (X) while rendering a different component (Y)` without it.